# What to focus on in the practise of sati?

Tags: daily-life, guidance, sati

Recently, I started to be aware of my actions as stated in Sathipattana sutta.

Today, I was aware about my movements when I moving a object. And I placed it in a wrong place. This happened multiple times.

Before this practise, I aware about where to put the object but not movements. But today, the opposite.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The Satipatthana Sutta does not instruct to be aware of bodily movements.

Instead, the Satipatthana Sutta instructs to know what you are doing according to the Dhamma when there are bodily movements. The Satipatthana Sutta says:

> Furthermore, a monks acts with **situational wisdom** when going out and
> coming back; when looking ahead and aside; when bending and extending
> the limbs; when bearing the outer robe, bowl and robes; when eating,
> drinking, chewing and tasting; when urinating and defecating; when
> walking, standing, sitting, sleeping, waking, speaking and keeping
> silent.
>
> Puna caparaṃ, bhikkhave, bhikkhu abhikkante paṭikkante sampajānakārī
> hoti, ālokite vilokite **sampajāna**kārī hoti, samiñjite pasārite
> sampajānakārī hoti, saṅghāṭipattacīvaradhāraṇe sampajānakārī hoti,
> asite pīte khāyite sāyite sampajānakārī hoti, uccārapassāvakamme
> sampajānakārī hoti, gate ṭhite nisinne sutte jāgarite bhāsite
> tuṇhībhāve sampajānakārī hoti.
>
> MN 10

For example, if you are perfectly aware of your bodily movements during the act of keeping silence and preparing a rifle to murder another person, this is not the practise of situational wisdom (sampajāna) because the bodily movements and actions are contrary to the path of Dhamma.

Again, if you are perfectly aware of your bodily movements during the act of taking drugs, engaging in sexual misconduct or maintaining the perfect quiet of a burglar robbing a rich man's house at night, this is not the practise of situational wisdom (sampajāna) because the bodily movements and actions are contrary to the path of Dhamma.

What the Satipatthana Sutta is instructing is meditating upon the body to ensure the body is engaged in wholesome dhammic bodily actions.

Comment: Who is responsible for that MN 10 translation?

Answer (score -2):

You have to practice four Satipathana. Contemplation on the body, feeling, thought, and Dhamma. The way you practice at the moment is not correct. It took me seven years just to scratch the surface of meditation. Just be patient, speak to a good teacher. Goenka's Ten days Vipassana course is a good way to start. There is a YouTube video series.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz7QHNvNFfA